# How to prove the determinant of covariance matrix is zero, when n≤p?

Tags: regression, covariance-matrix, singular-matrix, determinant

If there are n observations on p dimensions, then the covariance matrix will be:

[image]

But when n≤p, its determinant will be zero.

I know it is because it becomes as a singular matrix, but I do not know what its proof process will be like.

Please tell me why the determinant is zero can be proved.

Thank you.

Comment: The matrix you write does not appear to have anything at all to do with "observations:" it is expressed in terms of *expectations* of what look to be random variables $X_i.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the covariance matrix but the sample covariance is singular when $n<p$. Assume zero-mean features for simplicity. $X^TX$ (which is scaled sample covariance) will be $p\times p$. Think of this matrix multiplication as $AB=X^TX$, where $A=X^T,B=X$. From linear algebra, we know that $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(B)\leq n<p$, and also the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#/Properties):
$$\text{rank(AB)}\leq \min(\text{rank(A)},\text{rank}(B))\leq n$$
which means (since $n<p$), $X^TX$ is not full rank and has zero-determinant.

Comment: What about the case $n=p$?

Comment: it’s not necessarily singular

Comment: In some cases it *is* necessarily singular.  Take, for instance, $n=p=1.$  (I interpret the question as referring to *empirical* covariances of "observations.")

Comment: Oh, yes. When $n=1$, variance will be always $0$ and therefore determinant will always be $0$.

Comment: What, then, happens in higher dimensions? ;-)